# What's a quick way to comment/uncomment lines in Navicat query editor?

Tags: navicat

In Navicat, how do I enclose a selection in a comment?

Is there a keyboard shortcut for this action?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Ctrl + /` - To comment a block of code

`Ctrl + Shift + /` - To uncomment a block of code

Comment: This doesn't work on Mac OS (Yosemite 10.10.5). I also tried `Cmd + /` and `Cmd + Shift + /` but to no avail. `Comment` and `Uncomment` exist in the `Format` menu but have no shortcut shown. Maybe there's a way to add one?

Comment: Mac You just hit Cmd + / to comment and uncomment

But it can get pretty weird sometimes because Mac.

Comment: Is there any way to change the keys? Because in windows it didn't work :(

Comment: For me on windows `ctrl + /` to comment. Just highlight the commented area and do it again to uncomment

Answer (score 3):

Place -- in front of the line.

Or if you want to comment a block place /* at the beginning and */ at the end of the block.

Answer (score 2):

Navicat For Mysql shortcut keys:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> - open a query window.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> - notes or comment in the SQL statement.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> - release notes or uncomment the Query.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> - run all query the SQL statement window.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> - run the SQL selected statement only.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> - open a new query window.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> - close current query window.